# Plugin for creating a group of administrators in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

We used to have a plugin in LR6 that used a specific user group, which also had the administrator role assigned to it, for several use cases.

However, when trying to replicate its logic on LR7, this plugin correctly imported the users from a remote data source and put the users into this group. I can see their profile, which seems to be exactly what we need: in the "Inherited Regular Roles" the Administrator role is present.

However, they cannot see the control panel.

In an experiment, I administratively created a user group and assigned the Administrator role to the group. same behavior here, they cannot see anything.

I am poking around the source code, and it seems some parts of the module do use:

> PortalPermissionUtil.contains(
>                   permissionChecker, ActionKeys.VIEW_CONTROL_PANEL)

Which seems to verify inherited roles... Am I missing anything?
Bottom line, it seems that I cannot create usergroups of administrators anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, yes I was missing something: a bug

https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-61319

So, this will be an issue till GA4 at least.